# Could not autowire. No beans of 'DSLContext' type found

Tags: java, spring, jooq

I would like to insert data in postgres database using Jooq
This is my Service class

```
@Service
public class EnvironmentService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnvironmentService.class);

    private final DSLContext context;

    public EnvironmentService(DSLContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

But I have this error

**Could not autowire. No beans of 'DSLContext' type found.**

Comment: What does the stack trace say? How did you configure Spring / Spring Boot? Please have a look at this useful resource, regarding what additional info would be useful to help reproduce your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project is already configured with

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you'll need to configure your own DSLContext as @Bean so that you can use it.

Based on the documentation https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html.

You can create passing connection and dialect.

Example:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , however I did pass the datasource in the application.yml file `spring:
  application:
    name: myApp
  jooq:
    sql-dialect: POSTGRES
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}`

Comment: You can still retrieve your connection property values from your application.yml and create a connection object like this example:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.16/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step4/